# Generic points of algebraic stacks

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-stacks, generic-points

I am aware that this is not a esearch question, but I don't know where else to ask. I have come across the fact that the stack of bundles of rank r and degree d  over a curve of genus g with a rational point over a field k has a generic point of trdeg $(g-1)r^2+1$. First of all, I guess that we are cosidering by defintion the representative of the generic pint of smallest trdeg. I also know that the dimension of the stack is $(g-1)r^2$. In general,  give a group G acting on a variety X, how can I compute the trdeg of the generic point of the quotient stack [X/G]?

Comment: $\dim(X)-\dim(G)+\dim(\text{generic stabilizer})$. This can be understood without stacks (or without generic points, for this matter): what is the smallest value of $\dim(Y)$ for a subvariety $Y\subset X$ such that $G\cdot Y\subset X$ is dense?